# use a for loop to create a column containing the count of value in other column

Tags: r, for-loop, count

First, I'm new to Stackoverflow and new to R. So please bear with me on potential misunderstandings and the like on my side.

I have a dataframe with several columns. I am trying to create a new column which would contain the count of the value in one of the other columns. The task specifies that I need to use a for loop to achive this even though it might not be the most effective or effecient method.

I have tried with this approach but for some reason it does not work.

```
for (i in nrow(df)) {
   df$new_col[i] <- sum(df$old_col == df$old_col[i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

If you have data like this:

```
old_col   name
   1       a
   1       b
   2       c
   3       d
```

The code should yield:

```
old_col   name   new_col
   1       a        2
   1       b        2
   2       c        1
   3       d        1
```

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: You need to give a range, `for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { .... `

Comment: Whoops! Thanks a lot! Feel a bit dumb for making such an obvious mistake, but thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your own code, just change `nrow(df)` to `1:nrow(df)`, and it should work perfectly:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$new_col[i] <- sum(df$old_col == df$old_col[i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Another approach:

```
new_col=sapply(df$old_col,function(x) sum(df$old_col == x, na.rm = TRUE) )
df<-cbind(df,new_col)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (Solution for very begineer):

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(i==1){
   df$new_col[i]=1 # For first point
  }
  else if(df$old_col[i]==df$old_col[i-1]){
   df$new_col[i]=df$new_col[i-1]+1 # If old_col values are same
  }
  else{
   df$new_col[i]=1  # When we have a new old_col value
  }
}
```

Output:

```
    old_col name new_col
1       1    a       1
2       1    b       2
3       2    c       1
4       3    d       1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is "count by groups" -- group by `old_col` and count the number of rows with that value of `old_col`.

This is a very common operation and data manipulation packages make it easy to do this. My personal choice of data package is `data.table`, where your operation can be expressed as:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # convert to data.table to 'unlock' the correct syntax
df[ , new_col := .N, by = old_col]
```

With your data:

```
df = data.frame(old_col = c(1, 1:3), name = letters[1:4])
```

output:

```
   old_col name new_col
1:       1    a       2
2:       1    b       2
3:       2    c       1
4:       3    d       1
```

If forced to do this with a `for` loop, I strongly recommend not using `1:nrow(df)`. Probably the most effective way is to use a `table`:

```
counts = as.data.frame(table(old_col = df$old_col))

for (ii in 1:nrow(counts)) {
  df$new_col[df$old_col == counts$old_col[ii]] = counts$Freq[ii]
}
```

This avoids repetitively counting the number of rows -- imagine in `old_col` you had 1,000,000 repetitions of `1`. You wouldn't want to coun't up to `1,000,000` one million times (once for each appearance of `1`); better to count 1,000,000 once only.

Answer (score 0):

Just missing the `1:` in the `for(i in 1:nrow(df))` line.

```
df <- 
tribble(
  ~old_col,   ~name,
  1,         "a",
  1,         "b",
  2,         "c",
  3,         "d")

df$new_col <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$new_col[i] <- sum(df$old_col == df$old_col[i], na.rm = TRUE)
}

#         old_col name  new_col
#          <dbl> <chr>   <int>
#   1       1      a      2
#   2       1      b      2
#   3       2      c      1
#   4       3      d      1
```